# The 'condition' attribute is invalid - The value '@contains(string, 'substring')' is not within allowed values range

Tags: xml, azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am writing a terraform code where I have to add a XML as well. I also want to add condition to xml for filtering with basepath. My substring will be a basepath. I am adding it like a below code

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "auth-policy" {   
     for_each            = azurerm_api_management_api.api   
     xml_content = <<XML
    <policies>
      <inbound>
        <cors allow-credentials="true">
          <allowed-methods>
            <method>*</method>
          </allowed-methods>
        </cors>
        <base />
        <set-header name="ApiKey" exists-action="skip">
            <value>Default</value>
        </set-header>
        <choose>
            <when condition='@(context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Forwarded-Host"))'>
                  <set-header name="X-Forwarded-Host" exists-action="override">
                      <value>@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToUri().Host)</value>
                  </set-header>
            </when>
        </choose>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@contains(${each.value.name}, 'substring')">
                <rate-limit-by-key calls="100" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","").AsJwt()?.Subject)" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <rate-limit-by-key calls="100000" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Subscription.Id)" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" require-scheme="Bearer"
          failed-validation-httpcode="401"
          failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
          <openid-config url="https://*******************" />
          <audiences>
            ...........
          </audiences>
          <issuers>
            ...............
          </issuers>
        </validate-jwt>
      </inbound>
      <backend>
        <base />
      </backend>
      <outbound>
        <base />
      </outbound>
      <on-error>
        <base />
      </on-error>
    </policies>   
XML
 }
```

but it throws error

> Code="ValidationError" Message="One or more fields contain incorrect values:" Details=[{"code":"ValidationError","message":"Error in element 'choose' on line 28, column 10: The 'condition' attribute is invalid - The value '@contains(string, 'sunstring')' is not within allowed values range."

Is my condition correct, or do we get basepath with a request where I can use it directly instead of `each.value.name`(I get the names of the APIs) ?
I am new to xml and APIM, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add all the relevant code to the question. Which provider is this, which resource? How are you providing the XML value to that resource?

Comment: I have added the code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would suggest in a case like this is to use the built-in [`templatefile`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile) function. This way, you do not have to specify the XML file inline, rather as a file with some placeholder variable names. For example, you could create a file in the same directory with the name `api_policy.xml.tftpl`. The `tftpl` suffix is just a sign it is a terraform template file. The content of the file would then be:

```
<policies>
      <inbound>
        <cors allow-credentials="true">
          <allowed-methods>
            <method>*</method>
          </allowed-methods>
        </cors>
        <base />
        <set-header name="ApiKey" exists-action="skip">
            <value>Default</value>
        </set-header>
        <choose>
            <when condition='@(context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Forwarded-Host"))'>
                  <set-header name="X-Forwarded-Host" exists-action="override">
                      <value>@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToUri().Host)</value>
                  </set-header>
            </when>
        </choose>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@contains(${api_name}, 'substring')">
                <rate-limit-by-key calls="100" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","").AsJwt()?.Subject)" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <rate-limit-by-key calls="100000" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Subscription.Id)" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" require-scheme="Bearer"
          failed-validation-httpcode="401"
          failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
          <openid-config url="https://*******************" />
          <audiences>
            ...........
          </audiences>
          <issuers>
            ...............
          </issuers>
        </validate-jwt>
      </inbound>
      <backend>
        <base />
      </backend>
      <outbound>
        <base />
      </outbound>
      <on-error>
        <base />
      </on-error>
    </policies>
```

Note that the `condition` line now has this:

```
when condition="@contains(${api_name}, 'substring')"
```

The `${api_name}` syntax tells terraform to look for values assigned to the variable with the same name which is provided when calling the `templatefile` function:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "auth-policy" {   
     for_each    = azurerm_api_management_api.api   
     xml_content = templatefile("${path.root}/api_policy.xml.tftpl", {
       api_name = each.value.name
     })
}
```