How to add policies for different APIs as per api requirement
I am writing a terraform code where I am writing xml as well. I have two APIs and different policy requirements. I am trying to achieve it as below code but it doesn't help. Does anyone know how to add policies according to the APIs requirement?
<choose>
     ########## API ONE ###########
     <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("ApiKey") == "Default")">
         <rate-limit-by-key calls="10" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Request.IpAddress)" />
     </when>
     ########## API TWO ###########
     <when condition="@(context.Subscription.Name.Contains("API_name") and context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("ApiKey") == "Default")">
          <rate-limit-by-key calls="2000" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","").AsJwt()?.Subject)" />
      </when>
      <otherwise>
           <rate-limit-by-key calls="10000" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Subscription.Id)" />
      </otherwise>


Resource azurerm_api_management_api_policy manages an API Management API Policy.
You can:

Use a single template file for all policies
Use separate templates, one per policy

Using separate policy files for each API
Advantages:

Simplicity: Each template file is simpler and easier to understand, as it only contains the configuration for one policy.
Isolation: Changes or errors in one template file don't affect the others.

Disadvantages:

Increased management: More files to manage and keep track of.
Potential redundancy: If there are common elements in the policies, they will be duplicated in each template file.

Example - consider the following folder structure:
policies/
  foo-policy.xml
  bar.policy.xml

And then create azurerm_api_management_api_policy resources for each policy.
Example:
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "foo" {
  api_name            = "foo-api"
  api_management_name = var.api_management_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  xml_content = file("${path.module}/policies/foo-policy.xml")
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "bar" {
  api_name            = "bar-api"
  api_management_name = var.api_management_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  xml_content = file("${path.module}/policies/bar-policy.xml")
}

Using one template file for the policies
As an alternative, you can have one single template for the API policies and use templatefile to generate the desired content.
Advantages:

Centralization: All policy configurations are in one place, making it easier to manage and understand the overall policy structure.
Reduced redundancy: If there are common elements in the policies, they can be defined once in the template, reducing duplication.
Dynamic generation: The policy can be dynamically generated based on variables, allowing for more flexible and programmable configuration.

Disadvantages:

Complexity: The template file can become complex and hard to read if there are many conditions or a lot of nested logic.
Risk of errors: A mistake in the template or in the variable values can affect all policies, not just one.

Example - file policies/policy-template.tpl
<choose>
  %{ if api_version == "one" ~}
  <when condition='@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("ApiKey") == "Default")'>
    <rate-limit-by-key calls="10" renewal-period="60" counter-key='@(context.Request.IpAddress)' />
  </when>
  %{ endif ~}
  %{ if api_version == "two" ~}
  <when condition='@(context.Subscription.Name.Contains("API_name") and context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("ApiKey") == "Default")'>
    <rate-limit-by-key calls="2000" renewal-period="60" counter-key='@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","").AsJwt()?.Subject)' />
  </when>
  <otherwise>
      <rate-limit-by-key calls="10000" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Subscription.Id)" />
  </otherwise>
  %{ endif ~}
</choose>

Terraform code:
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "one" {
  api_name            = "one-api"
  api_management_name = var.api_management_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  xml_content = templatefile("${path.module}/policies/policy-template.tpl", {
    api_version = "one"
  })
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "two" {
  api_name            = "two-api"
  api_management_name = var.api_management_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  xml_content = templatefile("${path.module}/policies/policy-template.tpl", {
    api_version = "two"
  })
}


Thank you Jarimba, I don't want to keep them in a seperate files. Is there any other way to do it in  a same resource

I am already checking here with API_name  <when condition='@(context.Subscription.Name.Contains("API_name") this will not work?

here is the link to a queation how my resouce looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78230034/the-condition-attribute-is-invalid-the-value-containsstring-substring/78230363#78230363

@Panda sorry I might have misunderstood what you were looking for because you didn't provide more details. Didn't you find what you were looking for in the other question? Anyway, I'll leave my answer here as it might be helpful to someone else with similar problems.

I have posted another question with more details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78275848/the-name-contains-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context
