The name 'contains' does not exist in the current context
I am new to APIM and XML, I want to check of the api name contains in a string(${each.value.name}) and then add rate limit in terraform xml. I had added policy for a API manually for api_a like
<when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("ApiKey") == "Default")">
      <rate-limit-by-key calls="100" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","").AsJwt()?.Subject)" />
</when>

I want to add a policy through terraform. I'm writing code as given below. I want to adjust manually added policy in existing policy in terraform code for api_a and also keep the policy added for a non-valid key <when condition='@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("ApiKey") == "Default")'> How to adjust a conditions so that I can add all manually added and existing code policy? I dont want to create seperate xml files and resources.
    resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "auth-policy" {   
         for_each            = azurerm_api_management_api.api   
         xml_content = <<XML
        <policies>
          <inbound>
            <cors allow-credentials="true">
              <allowed-methods>
                <method>*</method>
              </allowed-methods>
            </cors>
            <base />
            <set-header name="ApiKey" exists-action="skip">
                <value>Default</value>
            </set-header>
            <choose>
                <when condition="@(contains("${join(",", ["api_a"])}", ${each.value.name}))">
                    <rate-limit-by-key calls="100" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","").AsJwt()?.Subject)" />
                </when>
               <when condition='@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("ApiKey") == "Default")'>
                <rate-limit-by-key calls="10" renewal-period="60" counter-key='@(context.Request.IpAddress)' />
               </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <rate-limit-by-key calls="100000" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Subscription.Id)" />
                </otherwise>
            </choose>
          </inbound>
        </policies>   
    XML
     }

When I apply above resource it gives error

Error: creating/updating Api Policy: (Policy Name "xml" / Api Name "api_av1" / Service Name "" / Resource Group "*********"): apimanagement.APIPolicyClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="ValidationError" Message="One or more fields contain incorrect values:" Details=[{"code":"ValidationError","message":"Error in element 'choose' on line 28, column 10: The name 'contains' does not exist in the current context","target":"choose"}]

Has anyone faced this issue, Please help me.
Thanks in advance

I could see that the issue is with contains function. Have you tried any other function instead of it. @Panda

@Jahnavi do you know how to do SSO for developer portal? I have a question posted here https://stackoverflow.com/q/78332602/8671089

What about the above issue? Is it solved? @Panda

yes it is solved in a different way. the requirement chnages and did not need this solution.
